# Number changes its value at client Javascript

Tags: javascript, browser, numbers

Whenever I write `23842899791470069` number into my browser's console it becomes `23842899791470068`. Observed this in chrome and firefox.
Can anyone confirm and explain the reason why is that so.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can confirm, can't explain. WEIRD ?!

23842899791470069 -> 23842899791470069
23842899791470070 -> 23842899791470070
23842899791470068 -> 23842899791470068
Why does only XX69 get decremented?

Answer (score 1):

Javascript uses 64-bit doubles for number representation, which means that integers larger than 2^52 (4,503,599,627,370,496) can't be represented accurately (essentially they lose their least significant bits, though it seems to be a bit more complicated).

Comment: But then why doesn't 23842899791470070 doesn't get decremented

Comment: @isaac because it can be represented exactly.

Comment: `essentially they lose their least significant bits` thats a bit missleading, its not that just some bits get shifted off at the end, its a bit more complicated

Comment: Yea I'm not sure why it's reducing mantissa by 1. Normally (as observed in C++), ...70 should be rounded up to ...72, but the opposite is happening in JS. Must be something in the spec about it.